# Qt read acces violation at:0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance)

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, null

I have a very simple piece of code as follows:

```
Letter* Vakje::geefLetter() const
{
    return m_letter;
}
```

The class Vakje gets initialized with a NULL-pointer for `m_letter`, but I'm still getting a read access violation error, could someone please help?

this is the code that calls the function:

```
bool Spelbord::positionIsEmpty(int rij, int kolom) { 
    if (vakjes[rij][kolom]->geefLetter()==nullptr) return true;
    else return false; 
}
```

Comment: Exactly what else do you expect? Accessing a pointer that is `NULL` is undefined behaviour, which is most cases means "crash the program" [not ALWAYS the case for UB, but in this sort of case, quite typical].

Comment: but I'm doing a check to see if it's NULL :S

Comment: I see no check. Were we supposed to guess that some of your code somewhere has a null-check? What else are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Which code shows the read access violation error? You are not showing client code.

Comment: There is nothing here. You can't talk about checks and violations without showing them.

Comment: Show us the surrounding code. I.e, what's calling it and what's using the result.

Comment: The containing Vakje object might be invalid/accessed via dangling pointer. Try with a debugger/and or Valgrind (if on Linux/OS X).

Comment: Are you calling `geefLetter` on a null Vakje?

Comment: this is the code:
bool Spelbord::positionIsEmpty(int rij, int kolom)
{
    if (vakjes[rij][kolom]->geefLetter()==nullptr)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

Comment: Edit your question to contain the relevant code please. Don't hide it within comments. And are you sure that the "table" has non-null Vakje-s?

Comment: @Cédric Please ask a _complete_ question, editing it to include all the relevant code.

Comment: I read this line `if (vakjes[rij][kolom]->geefLetter()==nullptr)...` as "Hello, I am a native 2D array and I am going to crash because you are going to call me with values of `rij` and `kolom` out of range. The question is not _if_ I am going to crash, but _when_".

Comment: the rij and kolom values can't go out of range :S

Comment: So answer this: what are the dimensions? When it crashes, what does it crash on (the indices)? Might it be that the Vakje is null? Did you check that? Fire up a debugger and let us know. (OT: might I advice you to start programming in English and not Dutch. You'll thank me in the future).

Comment: Vakje was null, sorry for the stupid question, thanks :)

Comment: @Cédric Out of range, null element, value not initialized... whatever.

Answer (score 2):

If `vakjes[rij][kolom]` is `NULL`, then trying to dereference that pointer `->` results in undefined behavior (usually: crash).

Just change the code to:

```
bool Spelbord::positionIsEmpty(int rij, int kolom) { 
  if (vakjes[rij][kolom] == nullptr) return true;
  if (vakjes[rij][kolom]->geefLetter()==nullptr) return true; 

  return false; 
}
```