# Error in Qt : how to resolve the error "error: Exception at 0x50d6f6de, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance)"

Tags: qt, exception, compiler-errors

My program shows an error while running.What is the cause of this error ?When willit happen ?
error: Debugger encountered an exception: Exception at 0x50d6f6de, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance)

Comment: Debug your program, find where the error is located, post the code here.

Comment: shows an error where? Might be nothing to worry about.

Comment: show your code, please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt read acces violation at:0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055292/qt-read-acces-violation-at0x0-flags-0x0-first-chance)

Comment: The problem is that accessing an unallocated memory space verifies that the pointer stores a correct address.

Comment: PopupServer::PopupServer(QWidget *parent)
{
    win=parent;
 }
void PopupServer::showPopup(const QString &text,const int &tim )
{
    QLabel *qPopup= new QLabel;
    qPopup->setText(text);
    qPopup->setFrameStyle(QLabel::Raised | QLabel::Panel);
    qPopup->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    qPopup->setFixedSize(200,100);
    int width;
    int height;
  ->  width=win->width(); // error located here
    height=win->height();
    qPopup->move(width-qPopup->width(),height-qPopup->height());
    qPopup->show();
    }

Comment: Please don't put large chunks of code in comments.  It should go in the question.  In your constructor you have `win = parent` and then later you dereference `win` with `width = win->width()` without ever checking to ensure `win` is non-null.

Comment: Got it.Thanks for the help.